# How to set a paraview server plugin property server side to later retrieve from client side

Tags: c++, paraview

I have an issue where my `pvserver` (with a custom plugin) has a source with a proxy property that can be set either algorithmically by the server, or manually by the user from the client. Setting the property manually from the client works as expected and can be retrieved from the server at a later point, but if the server sets the value, the client cannot retrieve that value. This is using paraview 5.11 built from source, using a local server and client on Linux (Artix, if that makes a difference).

The xml for the plugin contains the following, by analogy from [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/-/blob/master/Remoting/Application/Resources/proxies_gdal.xml):

```
<IntVectorProperty
    command="GetScaleFactor"
    information_only="1"
    name="ScaleFactorInfo">
  </IntVectorProperty>

  <IntVectorProperty
    command="SetScaleFactor"
    default_values="1"
    information_property="ScaleFactorInfo"
    name="ScaleFactor"
    number_of_elements="1">
    <Documentation>
      This property can be used to read only every inc-th pixel along the dimensions of the image.
    </Documentation>
  </IntVectorProperty>
```

This works perfectly fine if the client side is setting the value, e.g.:

```
...
//Set ScaleFactor using the user's choice if not autoscaled
if (!useAutoScale)
    vtkSMPropertyHelper(src->getProxy(), "ScaleFactor").Set(client_choice_num);

...
//time passes
...

//Retrieve ScaleFactor
int scaleFac;
vtkSMPropertyHelper(src->getProxy(), "ScaleFactor").Get(&scaleFac);

//use the retrieved ScaleFactor on the client side
```

However, when this property is set algorithmically by the server, the reading step does not work. E.g., on the custom plugin side, with the header and class as follows:

```
//myCustomReader.h

class VTK_EXPORT myCustomReader : public vtkMPIImageReader
{
  public:
    ...
    vtkGetMacro(ScaleFactor, int);
    vtkSetMacro(ScaleFactor, int);
    ...
  protected:
    ...
  private:
    ...
    /**
     * @brief This property can be used to read only every inc-th pixel along the
     * dimensions of the image.
     *
     */
    int ScaleFactor;
};

//myCustomReader.cxx
    ...
    //if the image should be scaled automatically
    if (AutoScale){
        int sf = calcScaleFactor(size, limit);
        this->SetScaleFactor(sf);
    }
    ...
    vtkDebugMacro(<< "Scale factor: " << this->GetScaleFactor())
    ...
```

The server’s debug output gives me the correct and expected value of sf, and the rendering behaviour is as expected. However, the value retrieved using the `vtkSMPropertyHelper` does not match and is only the default 1. Again, it works perfectly if it is first set from the client side and then retrieved.

I would like to know why setting the property value on the server side does not allow for retrieval by the client, and if there is a way to do it without moving the calculation to the client side.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Store the info property separately the the standard property in the VTK object.

Comment: @MathieuWestphal Do you mean something like `int ScaleFactorInfo` with associated getter and setter in the `MyCustomReader.h` file, with a corresponding change in the plugin xml? I tried that to no avail.

Comment: Yes, but no setter needed